# Rendering only a specific fraction of raster values

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster where each pixel has a continuous value 0-1. I would like to indicate which 25%  (for example) of the area corresponding to the raster contains the highest values i.e. indicate where the top 25% of values are located. Is it possible to do this somehow simply in Layer Properties using QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

For a layer property method you can try the following:

In the symbology of your raster set render type to `Singleband pseudocolor`. Use mode `Quantile`. Change the number of classes to 4. Now make the lower 3 classes transparent by going into the colour settings and turning the opacity to 0%.

Comment: I did something similar at first using mode Continuous, but is this not just rendering all pixels with a value ≥0.75 regardless of how much of the area they cover? What I want to do is render the 25% of the area that comprises the highest values, where some areas will have no values >0.75. Additionally, when I switch to Quantile mode, the value for each class changes to "nan" and no pixels are rendered, although I can still derive their values using the Identify Features tool, it is just white space.

Comment: As far as I am aware, using quantile mode will divide your dataset into four classes, each containing 25% of your data. (see also: http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Quantile). Not sure where the "nan" problem is coming from, but did you try to "classify" the values again?

Comment: Yes, you're right, quantile classification will give me what I'm looking for. I did try to classify the values but still get the same "nan" value for all 4 classes. The issue is the same for 6 other rasters of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try using GRASS-GIS, this operation is simple. GRASS has a module `r.quantile` for calculating any quantiles of a raster map. The default number of quantiles is four, so you get the first 25%, the first 50% (median value), and the 75% quantile. The output of this module is a list of the quantile values. This list can then be "fed" into an `r.reclass` statement to get the new reclassed raster with value 1,2,3,4 representing each of the four quantiles. If you want only the top 25%, you then run `r.mapcalc` on the reclassed raster to get only those pixels.

Here's how it goes from the GRASS command line, assuming I have a raster called srtm30:

```
# Use the -r option to r.quantile get output in the reclass format
micha@tp480:$ r.quantile -r srtm30
Computing histogram
 100%
Computing bins
Binning data
 100%
Sorting bins
Computing quantiles
-4094.000000:-2779.000000:1
-2779.000000:-1266.000000:2
-1266.000000:-48.000000:3
-48.000000:56.000000:4
 
# Now put those values into a reclass rules text file
echo "-4094 thru -2779 = 1 25%
-2779 thru -1266 = 2 50%
-1266 thru -48 = 3 75%
-48 thru 56 = 4 100%" > srtm_rcl.txt

# And run r.reclass with that rules file
micha@tp480:$ r.reclass srtm30 output=srtm_reclass rules=srtm_rcl.txt
micha@tp480:$ r.mapcalc "srtm_25pcent = if(srtm_reclass==1, srtm30, null())"
```

The above `r.mapcalc` expression will set all pixels in the **bottom** 25 percentile to their original raster values, and all other pixels will be NULL. You can tune this to your needs, of course.

HTH